# Java module ResolutionException module A does not read a module that exports B

Tags: java, jvm, java-module

I want to write a `JVMCI` based compiler, but I am getting some problems. I have a module A:

```
module A {
  requires jdk.internal.vm.ci;
  opens pkg;

  provides jdk.vm.ci.services.JVMCIServiceLocator with
        pkg.AServiceLocator;
}
```

`AServiceLocator` extends `JVMCIServiceLocator` so that, it could locate `JVMCI service`. When I tried to pack A into a jar, JVM throws an exception -

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module A does not read a module that exports jdk.vm.ci.services
```

I was confused, what should I do? Is there any `JVMCI` tutorial or documentation?

Comment: The error seems to be pointing to the fact that you do not have that module on the module path

Answer (score 0):

I met with a similar problem and here is my solution:

1. Rename `module A` to `module jdk.internal.vm.compiler`. You will get something like this:

```
module jdk.internal.vm.compiler {
  requires jdk.internal.vm.ci;
  opens pkg;

  provides jdk.vm.ci.services.JVMCIServiceLocator with
        pkg.AServiceLocator;
}
```

2. Package your module in `.jar`, i named it `MyEmptyCompiler.jar`
3. Try start your java with such parameters:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java --upgrade-module-path <path-to-your-jar>/MyEmptyCompiler.jar -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCI -XX:+UseJVMCICompiler -Djvmci.Compiler=<your-compiler-name> -version
```

`<your-compiler-name>` it is name which you define in `JVMCICompilerFactory` successor `public String getCompilerName()` method. In my particular case it looks like this:

```
public class MyEmptyCompilerFactory extends HotSpotJVMCICompilerFactory {

    public MyEmptyCompilerFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getCompilerName() {
        return "MyEmptyCompilerFactory";
    }

    @Override
    public JVMCICompiler createCompiler(JVMCIRuntime rt) {
        return new MyEmptyCompiler();
    }

}
```

And my command-line looks like this:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java --upgrade-module-path ~/ct/MyEmptyCompiler.jar -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCI -XX:+UseJVMCICompiler -Djvmci.Compiler=MyEmptyCompilerFactory -version
```

Result of work of this cmd:

```
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.32+13-CA (build 17.0.2+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.32+13-CA (build 17.0.2+8-LTS, compiled mode)
```